# nighttime checking function c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, function

We need a night-time formula of 2 dates. This is supposed to be a boolean function that receives 2 dates (their time difference is no more than 12 hours) and checks for nighttime hours, nighttime hours are set from 00:00 to 6:00 am,
The function results in the following cases:

**1/1/18** 20:00 - **2/1/18** 7:00 `true`

**2/1/18** 1:00   - **2/1/18** 7:00 `true`

**2/1/18** 1:00   - **2/1/18** 5:15 `true`

**1/1/18** 20:00 - **1/1/18** 23:00 `false`

**1/1/18** 20:00 - **2/1/18** 3:30 `true`

my work( not working for all cases)

```
     private bool CheckNightHours(DateTime start, DateTime end)
     {
         var nightStart = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day ,0 ,0, 0);// 00:00;         
         var nightEnd = new DateTime(end.Year, end.Month, end.Day, 6, 0, 0); // 6:00;
         bool result = false;

         if (end < nightStart)
            return false;
         else { 
            if (start > nightStart && end > nightStart)
               result = false;
            else
            if ((end >= nightEnd) || (end > nightStart && end < nightEnd))
               result = true;        
            else   
               return result;
         }
      }
```

Comment: Add 12 hour to start time and then make sure end time is greater than start time and end time is less the start time plus 12 hours.

Comment: So basically you want to know if the range of Datetime values you supply to the function [overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) the range of time values between 00:00 and 06:00.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: yes, i tried so far, and i dont found a condition that all cases resolved,@jdweng i'm not asking to check if date difference bigger than 12, we are Assuming the date difference smaller than 12 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work

```
public static bool IsNight(DateTime from, DateTime to)
   => (to > from) && (from < from.Date.AddHours(6) || to < to.Date.AddHours(6) || to > from.Date.AddDays(1));
```

**Update**

Or even better as suggested by [@ZoharPeled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094533/zohar-peled)

```
public static bool IsNight(DateTime from, DateTime to)
   => (to > from) && ( rom.Hour < 6 || to.Hour < 6 || to > from.Date.AddDays(1));
```

The premise is,

- `to` is greater than `from` (sanity check)
- `from` is less than 6am (all other `to`'s would be a valid night)
- `to` is less than 6am, (all other `fro`m's would be a valid night)
- `to` in the next day to `from`, it must be over a night

You could add another sanity check for 24 hours i guess

***Note*** : this will only work since the nighttime is declared to start at midnight

Comment: Already upvoted even before :-) But you might want to also add a bullet saying this will only work since the nighttime is declared to start at midnight. If it was starting at 01:00 you would have false positives, and if it was starting at 23:00 you would have false negatives.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime firstTime = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0);
            DateTime secondTime = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0);

            DateTime midNight = new DateTime(firstTime.Year, firstTime.Month, firstTime.Day, 12, 0, 0).AddHours(12);
            DateTime AM6 = midNight.AddHours(6);

            if(firstTime < midNight)
            {
                if(midNight < secondTime)
                    return true;

                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (secondTime < AM6)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: failure at the second case 2/1/18 1:00 - 2/1/18 7:00

Answer (score 1):

[TheGeneral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/thegeneral) posted a good answer, but it will only work since the nighttime starts at midnight.
A more general solution would be to create another range of DateTime for the nighttime and check for overlaps - so you where on the right track creating `DateTime` values from the start time and end time and check if the date range overlaps - but the code for testing if the ranges overlap was wrong.

From the [overlap](/questions/tagged/overlap) tag wiki:

> The way to find if the elements overlap or not is to test if one elements begins before the second one ends, while the second one begins before the first one ends.

So a better code would be this:

```
 private bool CheckNightHours(DateTime start, DateTime end)
 {  
     var nightStart = start.Date.AddDay(); 
     var nightEnd = end.Date.AddHours(6);
     bool result = false;

     return nightStart < end && start < nightEnd;
  }
```

I've also simplified code you've used to create the `nightStart` and `nightEnd` values as a bonus.

Comment: @vhkvua yes - the `Date` property basically truncates the hours away from the `DateTime` so you get midnight of that date, and you add a day because you want the midnight right after the start date.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative is not such elegant as before, but I have bad experiences from counting time like math values. It could lead to common filter bugs from time format changes. Up to you, what do you prefer.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startTime">First Datetime</param>
    /// <param name="span">12 hours in your case</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool AnyNightHoursIncluded(DateTime startTime, int span)
    {
        int startHour = Convert.ToInt32(startTime.ToString("HH")); //24 hour format
        for (int i = 0; i < span; i++)
        {
            int actualHourValue = Convert.ToInt32(startTime.AddHours(i).ToString("HH"));
            //from 0:00 to 6:00
            if (actualHourValue >= 0 && actualHourValue < 6)
                return true;      
        }
        return false;
    }
```